# How to have localStorage data persist

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm kind of racking my brain over how to get data to persist in localStorage while also adding new data. The jist of what I'm doing is creating a quiz that will store the users initials and their score into localStorage so that when refreshed and the user chooses to retrieve the high scores they'll be displayed. I'm having trouble where it gets to the end of my app and the data that's already there is completely overwritten. Any help is appreciated.

```
function saveScore() {
    var data = [{name: userInitialsEl.value}, {score: scoreCount}];
    localStorage.setItem("high-score", JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

userInitialsEl is a text input. scoreCount is the score that's incremented as the user answers questions correctly.

Comment: how about checking the high-score item before setting? if exist => compare then update, if not exist, setItem(),...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the current data first then push in the new one before saving it back, you can do something like this:

```
function saveScore() {
  let newData = !!localStorage.getItem("high-score") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("high-score")) : []
  newData.push([{name: userInitialsEl.value}, {score: scoreCount}])
  localStorage.setItem("high-score", JSON.stringify(newData));
    
}
```

Comment: `localStorage.getItem(...)` could be undefined so `JSON.parse` is not gonna always work, you should add a fallback like: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(...) || "{}")`

Comment: While I didn't do exactly what you've stated I did however JUST figure out that I needed to retrieve the data and then push the new data in before setting it again. Thank you so much!

Comment: no worries, also check first if "high-score" has been previously defined in the localStorage before doing the getItem()